# Error in C++ code

Tags: c++, oop

The code is written to implement a Bit class with some common functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Bit
{ 
    int width;
    int value;
    public:
        Bit(int v, int w)
        {
            value=v;
            width=w;
        }
        Bit(const Bit& b)
        {
            value= b.value;
            width= b.width;
        }
        int getWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }
        int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
        Bit plus(int newval)
        {
            value+=newval;
            if(value>=pow(2,width))
            cout<<"Overflow";
            return this;
        }
};
```

The error message is :

```
Conversion from 'Bit* const' to non-scalar type 'Bit' requested.
```

How can i remove the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, and your `plus` function declares that it returns a value.

You probably want to change the return type to `void` and not return anything; I can't see a good reason to return a copy of the object.

Perhaps you want to return a reference in order to chain calls:

```
Bit & plus(int newval)        //< added &
{
    value+=newval;
    if(value>=pow(2,width))
        cout<<"Overflow";
    return *this;             //< added *
}
```

now you can write:

```
bit.plus(1).plus(3).plus(42);
```

if you really want to.

Comment: what happens if i change the constructor to something like   `Bit(Bit b)
{
 value= b.value;
 width= b.width;
}
` Why is this erroneous here but it works perfectly in java.

Comment: The copy constructor must take its argument by reference; in order to pass it by value, you'd need the copy constructor to create the value - which is impossible, since this *is* the copy constructor. In Java, the argument is a reference - you can't pass class types by value at all. In C++, you have to declare that it's a reference, `Bit(Bit const & b)`.

Answer (score 3):

Method `plus(int newval)` should return `*this;` instead of `this`. That's the error. Also return value of type `Bit&` (reference) would make more sense. Although you probably don't need to return a reference to the object that you have used to call this method (check Mike's answer).

Also note that `pow(2,width)` is equal to `(1 << width)`.

Comment: You are right. But I would like to know why do we need pointer there? I heard "this" is a pointer then why do we need to add another pointer? I am new to C++, could you pls explain?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: You don't *"add another pointer"*, you are dereferencing existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Your "**plus**" method returns "Bit* const". I guess whole method should be

```
Bit& plus(int newval)
{
 value+=newval;
 if(value>=pow(2,width))
 cout<<"Overflow";
 return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Bit & plus(...) { ... return *this; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if you could add the line number, or just give the function where it fails. However, this seems to be where it stops.

```
Bit plus(int newval)
{
 value+=newval;
 if(value>=pow(2,width))
 cout<<"Overflow";
 return this;
}
```

The thing is, this is a pointer to the object. That means this is actually a `Bit *`. Since you want to return a Bit, this will create a failure as you describe. To fix this you could change it to:

```
Bit& plus(int newval)
{
  value+=newval;
  if(value>=pow(2,width))
    cout<<"Overflow";
  return *this;
}
```

Which would return a reference to the updated object. You could of course also return a `Bit*`, but I would try to avoid using pointers unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bit plus(int newval)
{
 value+=newval;
 if(value>=pow(2,width))
 cout<<"Overflow";
 return this;
}
```

This methot returns a Bit but you return a pointer to Bit.
You should return:
`return *this` , or the method signature should be `Bit* plus(int newval)` (if you decide to return "this")